# I am typing into my terminal and the stdin is changing and adding characters on its own

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, command-line, zsh

I am using `curl` on my Macos Catalina terminal app, and the text I enter in **stdin** gets altered on me pressing enter <kbd>Enter</kbd>. For a simple example:

```
curl -d " 印度是最好的 The weather is good" -X POST http://localhost:8000/questions/21/
curl: (1) Protocol "hhttp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

is actually entered as :

```
 curl -d " 印度是最好的 The weather is good" -X POST hhttp://localhost:8000/questions/21/
```

, which I can see from previous command on terminal <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

P.S - I've entered the command and thus, it shows libcurl error.

For an english sentence - you can see the error below:

[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd1Hf.jpg)

I have no idea why this is happening, I'm using **zsh** shell and `ohmyzsh` along with it - and this is happening the first time to me.

Adding an image here too, for further investigation.

[terminal typing problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUKJ.jpg)

My **.zshrc** configuration is [here](https://gist.github.com/sirius0503/226d23a19bac5bc869e46b50a1024d3b)

Comment: Probably a bug in [tag:terminal]. I tried copy-pasting the line you posted into Terminal.app on macOS Big Sur and it does not work at all. It basically breaks from the first Chinese character onwards.

Comment: @MarlonRichert - Actually, it isn't a problem with **chinese** text, it happens to me for regular english text too!

Comment: Turn off OhMyZsh (and leave it off, it's a cancer).  Does the problem still occur?

Comment: There isn't enough information to help you here. It's difficult to diagnose this without trying things out. To get help, you need to figure out a way other people can reproduce the problem. The first step is to see if you can reproduce in another terminal window. Then, see if you can reproduce without your `.zshrc`; if you can't, you'll need to post your complete `.zshrc` and all the files it loads. If you can reproduce it without Chinese text, it would help.

Comment: Does it matter whether you typed the command or copy-pasted? Can you reproduce this with commands other than `curl`? If you press Up to edit the command line, does the extra `h` appear? If you run `fc` to edit the last command in an external editor, does the extra `h` appear? Is the problem always with the letter `h` or sometimes with other letters? Does the problem occur with every `h` or only some? Does the problem occur with other terminals such as iTerm?

Comment: Hi @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - Yes. I can reproduce the same on another terminal window. Also, I can reproduce the problem without chinese text as shown in the imgur pic I uploaded via edit. I'll try to remove my .zshrc file and try it out. Also, if I type it I also I can find the error too!, apart from it happening upon copy-pasting and trying to edit a previous command (found from **UP** or **Control+ P**. Yes, the extra **h** does appear from history. Yes, the extra **h** appears from **fc** command too. The problem isn't always with the character **h**, it can be  any letter in sentence.

Comment: The error can be in any part of the sentence, even in the data part.  Just tried `iterm2`, the same error doesn't emulate on it. I can easily edit on it without any mistakes and copy paste on it too - no errors on it

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' : Also, removed my **.zshrc** file and I don't get the error anymore. Will add my **.zshrc** file in the question. Also, apologies for being so late in replying to your query about the question.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any problem with trying to paste that line into zsh running in Terminal.app.  Some testing...

```
zsh: processed normally
dash: processed normally
oksh: processed normally
pdksh: processed normally
tcsh: processed normally
bash: processed normally
fish: processed normally
ksh: takes the Chinese as editor commands and weirds out
```

I'll report that as a ksh bug, I suppose.

But your problem would seem to be OhMyZsh, not Terminal.app.  I can replicate the ksh behavior in iTerm as well.

Edit: ksh has a bug with multibyte characters and the KEYBD trap.  See https://github.com/ksh93/ksh/issues/307 and https://github.com/att/ast/issues/197